# Python - How to print a whole url in a for loop not just characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a variable called `all_urls`- it contains a list of URLs, for example:

```
https://website.com/image1
https://website.com/image2
https://website.com/image3
```

I want to print each URL using a for loop.

```
for url in all_urls:
        print(url)
```

but what I end up getting is:

```
h
t
t
p
s
(and so on)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it so the program returns each URL?
Thanks.

Comment: all_urls.split()

Comment: `for url in all_urls.splitlines():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
for url in all_urls.split('\n'):
    print(url)
```

What I'm thinking is that you have a string rather than a list, so when you cycle over all elements of your variable, it just prints the single character.

In this way, `split('\n')` will allow to generate a list by splitting on the new line, each of which element will be the single url.